# Set id from variable for each item

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to apply an anchor based on child and then create the ID for the anchor with same value. First half, the anchor, is working.

Applying this

```
$(".horizontal-tab-button a").each(function() {
    var anchorid = $(this).attr('href', '#' + $(this).children('strong').html().replace(/ /g,"_").toLowerCase());
    $(".horizontal-tab-button a strong").attr('id', anchorid);
});
```

To this

```
<li class="horizontal-tab-button">
  <a href="#">
    <strong>Application</strong>
  </a>
</li>
```

Gives

```
<li class="horizontal-tab-button">
  <a href="#application">
    <strong id="[object Object]">Application</strong>
  </a>
</li>
```

The error is **[object Object]**, it should be `<strong id="application">`

`.attr('id' + anchorid);` doesn't give anything.

Live example https://jsfiddle.net/qyr0xk1e/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `.attr()` to set an attribute it returns a jQuery object, not the attribute string. Just store the attribute in a variable and then use it to set the attributes.

```
$(".horizontal-tab-button a").each(function() {
    var anchorid = $(this).children('strong').html().replace(/ /g,"_").toLowerCase();
    $(this).attr('href', '#' + anchorid).find('strong').attr('id', anchorid);
});
```

Comment: Any idea why it's not showing/updating in the address bar when clicked?

Answer (score 1):

This is because your variable is actually executing a method.

`var anchorid = $(this).attr(...);`

Try this instead:

```
var anchorid = $(this).children('strong').html().replace(/ /g, "_").toLowerCase();

$(".horizontal-tab-button a strong").attr('id', anchorid);
$(".horizontal-tab-button a strong").attr('href', '#' + anchorid);
// don't forget to actually reassign the href, since it has now been moved out of the variable
```

Answer (score 1):

`$(this).attr(...)` doesn't return the value of the attribute. It [returns jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2).

So when you do this:

```js
var anchorid = $(this).attr('href', '#' + $(this).children('strong').html().replace(/ /g,"_").toLowerCase());
```

`anchorid` is ***jQuery***, not ***"application"***. Which you then set as the `id` on your `strong` element, hence the stringified object: `[object Object]`